# "The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am trying to use the mediator pattern in my api but am getting some errors I don't understand. Here is the error  "The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments.

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public abstract class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IMediator _mediator;

        protected IMediator Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>();



    }
```

Comment: Do you have `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` ?

Comment: If you want to call it.... serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IService)).... this is the way.

Answer (score 2):

Adding using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection manually helped me.

Also you might want to consider using .GetRequiredService<>() which throws an Exception if the service is not registered, which might help better debug.

Also, although you can still use IMediator, you might want to consider using ISender to be more strict about it.

Comment: helpefull. solved my problem.